# Cancelling a ongoing network call subscription with RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

So I am trying to build a dialog fragment screen (Android) which has an `EditText` where users can input their desired username. Using the RxBindings library's `RxTextView.textChanges()` I am observing the `EditText` and doing the following:

1. Resetting existing hints and disabling the "Confirm" button.
2. Filtering out invalid strings using a regex pattern.
3. Making a request to the server to check if the valid string is available.
4. Showing the appropriate response and, if applicable, enabling the "Confirm" button.

My repository's `checkUsername()` method returns a `Single<Boolean>` to denote whether the username was available or not. Here's the code:

```
    Observable<String> usernameObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(usernameEditText)
            .doOnNext(charSequence -> resetUsernameChecks())
            .filter(charSequence -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence))
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(CharSequence::toString)
            .filter(s -> {
                boolean match = s.matches("^(?=.{4,12}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$");
                if (!match) showMessage(R.string.profile_dialog_username_hint_invalid, true);
                return match;
            });

    Disposable usernameSubscription = usernameObservable
            .subscribe(username -> {
                Disposable d = viewModel.checkUsername(username)
                        .subscribe(available -> {
                            if (available) {
                                claimButton.setEnabled(true);
                                showMessage(R.string.profile_dialog_username_hint_available, false);
                            } else {
                                showMessage(R.string.profile_dialog_username_hint_unavailable, true);
                            }
                        });
                disposables.add(d);
            });

    disposables.add(usernameSubscription);
```

With the following helper methods:

```
@UiThread
private void resetUsernameChecks() {
    claimButton.setEnabled(false);
    usernameInputLayout.setError(null);
}

@UiThread
private void showMessage(@StringRes int message, boolean error) {
    showMessage(getString(message), error);
}

@UiThread
private void showMessage(String message, boolean error) {
    if (error) {
        usernameInputLayout.setErrorTextAppearance(R.style.AppTheme_RedMessage);
    } else {
        usernameInputLayout.setErrorTextAppearance(R.style.AppTheme_GreenMessage);
    }

    usernameInputLayout.setError(message);
}
```

However, the issue I run into is <s>*that either of the `showMessage()` methods cause a crash because the there may either be a background thread in the running (thus preventing changes to the UI) or*</s> that a previously called `checkUsername()` lingers back and messes everything up.

Essentially, **how can I <s>make sure I do work on the correct thread and</s> cancel any lingering network calls before making a new one?**

**EDIT:
I fixed the thread issue by encapsulating the UI methods inside a Runnable. However, I still have issue with cancelling previous call. Lets say the user searches for an available username -- *nick* -- but then quickly hits backspace. The already fired network call now comes back and inaccurately shows that *nic* is available even though it may not be.**

Answer (score 0):

So, for you to update UI, you gotta do it in UI Thread. I guess,

```
usernameInputLayout.setErrorTextAppearance(R.style.AppTheme_GreenMessage);
```

is like the UI thread thing, so you need to use subscribeOn.

If you would show more from the log, we would know the error. But, right now, your best option is to use UI Thread to update UI.

```
usernameObservable.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> //whatever you want )
```

Edit: My bad about "Observable by default runs on background thread." It is wrong. The correct is: **It runs in the thread it is defined in, unless we use subscribeOn()/observeOn() methods.**

Comment: Updated my post with the relevant stacktrace. However, like i said that does not work because the UI thread is being touched before subscription as well.

Comment: "Observable by default runs on background thread" - this is not true. RxJava is not opinionated about your thread. It is executing on the thread you are subscribing on (subscribeOn) or switching to with observeOn. If no operator is provided it use's calling thread. Please change your answer corresponding.